# C# syntax sugar in three conditions

Tags: c#, syntax, operators

I want to know syntax sugar in C#.

```
var name = side=="BUY" ? "LONG" : "SHORT";
```

->It's very simple.

But there is possibility of the value except "BUY" and "SELL" in side.
The following is redundant.
Please tell me the simple expression.

```
var name;
if (side == "BUY")
    name="LONG";
else if(side="SELL")
    name="SHORT";
else
    throw Exception();
```

Comment: `switch-case`?.

Comment: Is there the syntax to set a return value in 'name variable' in switch-case?

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand what you mean.

Comment: The following is redundunt.

`var side = "NEITHER";
            var name="";
            switch(side)
            {
                case "BUY": name = "LONG";break;
                case "SELL": name = "SHORT"; break;
                default:throw new Exception();
            }`

Comment: I think you mis-use the "redundant" word. Do you actually mean "bloated"?

Comment: Alternatively you can create a dictionary from site to name. But for just 2 values it would be overkill.

Comment: sorry, I mean 'bloated'.
It is simple if I use the dictionary which told me.
Thank you.

`Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict["BUY"] = "LONG";
            dict["SELL"] = "SHORT";

            string side1 = "BUY";
            string name1 = dict[side1];


            string side2 = "NEITHER";
            string name2 = dict[side2];`

Comment: It would be even shorter if you use the collection initialiser: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few shorter ways to throw Exception (all case sensitive):

```
string name1 = side == "BUY" ? "LONG" : side == "SELL" ? "SHORT" : throw new Exception();

string name2 = new[] { "LONG", "SHORT" }[Array.IndexOf(new[] { "BUY", "SELL" }, side)]; // System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

string name3 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "BUY", "LONG" }, { "SELL", "SHORT" } }[side]; // System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind nesting the ternary:

```
var name = side == "BUY"
    ? "LONG"
    : side == "SELL"
        ? "SHORT"
        : "NEITHER";
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m5g1xT).

If you must throw an exception in the "NEITHER" case, but would prefer something other than if - else if - else construct, then a switch approach could be:

using System;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var side = "Foo";   // or "BUY" or "SELL" or whatever
        var name = "NEITHER";
        switch (side)
        {
            case "BUY":
                name = "LONG";
                break;
            case "SELL":
                name = "SHORT";
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uNil4b).

Comment: That should come with "don't do that at home" :-)

Comment: @kyounoii I think then your approach of if-else if-else is best. Each term of ternary must produce value of same type.

Answer (score 1):

Using switch expression:

```
string name = side switch
{
    "BUY" => "LONG",
    "SELL" => "SHORT",
    _ => throw new Exception()
};
```